# MySQL MyISAM Table File is now Too Large

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a MySQL MyISAM Table that handles Medium Blob Data. Now it reaches up to 1.09TB. I am worried about it now. Is it possible to split this table into multiple Files? File.MYD01, File.MYD01,... etc.

Or in case, if you have a better idea for an alternative path to take on, would love to hear.

(Added from a Comment:)

```
CREATE TABLE fileTBL (
    fileID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    docID int(11) NOT NULL, 
    versionID int(11) NOT NULL, 
    docCode varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
    fileData mediumblob, 
    docSalt varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (fileID), 
    KEY DocVersion (versionID,docID)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: 1.09TB? Woa! What are you storing there?

Comment: I am storing encrypted Binary Blob :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

For a long time the default limit for MyISAM data size has been 2^48 bytes.  For indexing, the default has been 2^40 rows for `FIXED` format, which is probably not your case -- since you have a `MEDIUMBLOB`.

2^48 is probably your only limit; that is 256TB.  You are a long way from hitting it.  The pain of doing `MERGE` or `PARTITION` is probably not worth it.  And you would *probably* gain *no* performance benefit.

[*More Limits*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits).

**Compression suggestion**

What kind of data is the blob before it is encrypted?  If it is text (or more like text than like images), you could compress it before encrypting it.  This is likely to shrink the space by a factor of 3.  (Of course, you can't get the space back until you `OPTIMIZE` or `ALTER` the table.)

Any change to the table will require at least enough space for a copy of the table.  If you can do that compression at the same time, it might require only 400GB of extra disk space.  Then you can drop the 1.09TB, leaving only 400GB.

Comment: Here's my Show Create Table for fileTBL, CREATE TABLE `fileTBL` (
  `fileID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `docID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `versionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `docCode` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `fileData` mediumblob,
  `docSalt` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fileID`),
  KEY `DocVersion` (`versionID`,`docID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: I moved the `CREATE` into the Question for clarity.

Comment: I added "compression suggestion" to my answer; see what you think.

Comment: files before encryption are PNG Image of the Document. Yes, it is also compressed before it was encrypted.

Comment: If you don't have an extra TB, there is nothing you can do.  But maybe ther is no "problem"; you are nowhere near hitting any limits.

Answer (score 1):

If your mysql installation supports it, you can use partitioning: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html

Comment: Which will work with MyISAM, but has some complicatons on Innodb and elsewhere. But its not possible to partition an existing dataset - you need to create a new (partitioned) table and copy over the data. This can be done with minimum downtime - have a look at Percona or Facebooks zero downtime schema change scripts.

Comment: @symcbean - What are the InnoDB 'complications'?

Comment: See Percona's `pt-online-schema-change`.  It does involve a `TRIGGER`, and requires enough disk space for an extra copy of the table.

Comment: @Rick: Foreign keys don't work and you need to be careful with optimization - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-storage-engines.html

Comment: (Yet another reason I eschew FKs.)